# HashMap in shell script with File path

Tags: arrays, shell, hashmap, syntax-error, filepath

I am trying to declare a hash map in shell script containing a file path as key and some variable as value.
Something like this

```
fileVarMap=( ["Dir1/file1.txt"]="myVar1"  ["Dir2/file2.txt"]="myVar2" )
```

I am getting an Error called...`syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator`

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Got One way to solve this 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4444841/1350792

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Bash, man page says :

> Associative arrays are created using declare -A name.

So, you should try this :

```
declare -A fileVarMap
fileVarMap=( ["Dir1/file1.txt"]="myVar1"  ["Dir2/file2.txt"]="myVar2" )
echo ${fileVarMap["Dir1/file1.txt"]}
```

Comment: Would you please provide a way to iterate this as key value :)

Comment: this was already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112687/how-to-iterate-over-associative-array-in-bash