# Accessing array index variable from bash shell script loop?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops

I want to access the array index variable while looping thru an array in my bash shell script.

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
A=('foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'bat')
for i in ${A[*]}; do
  echo $i
done
```

Actual result

```
foo
bar
baz
bat
```

Desired result

```
0
1
2
3
```

How do I alter my script to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over index using indirect reference syntax ([since Bash 3](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#metadata)) :

```
#!/bin/bash

A=('foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'bat')
for i in ${!A[*]}; do # replace ${A[*]} with ${!A[*]}
  echo $i
done
```

For more : [How to iterate over associative arrays in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112687/how-to-iterate-over-associative-array-in-bash)