# Error: must use subscript when assigning associative array

Tags: bash

I wanted a hashmap equivalent in bash (keys as `string` and values as a `list` of integers). So, I wrote the following code-

```
declare -A PUBS

PUBS=( "FEE":"[345, 342]" "FOO":"[1, 2, 44]" "BAR":"[23, 67]" )
```

However, I get an error saying `must use subscript when assigning associative array`.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Since `[345, 342]` isn't any kind of `bash` literal, you might as well dispense with the unnecessary brackets and comma and just write `PUBS=([FEE]="345 342" [FOO]="1 2 44" [BAR]="23 67")`.

Comment: Got it, but does it hurt to have it like that in the code? The main reason is that I want to pass all these values as a list parameter to a Python file.

Comment: That would assume your Python program is using something like `eval` to create a list from a string argument, right? That's probably a bad idea.

Comment: @chepner Oh, what do you recommend then? How do I pass these values `[345, 342]`? And how do I parse them in my Python program to make a list?

Comment: The simplest thing (assuming there are no other arguments), would be to pass each integer as a separate argument, and have Python collect them into a list itself. A proper treatment deserves its own question, though.

Comment: @chepner `ast.literal_eval()` is a fine way to parse something like this in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using the correct syntax to specify the keys. It's `[key]=value`, not `key:value`. So it should be:

```
PUBS=( ["FEE"]="[345, 342]" ["FOO"]="[1, 2, 44]" ["BAR"]="[23, 67]" )
```

Comment: a quick follow-up question- How do I loop through this hashmap? I want to get the keys and values for each iteration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112687/how-to-iterate-over-associative-arrays-in-bash