# Shell - How to declare an associative array and iterate through

Tags: arrays, shell, for-loop

I am trying to declare an associative array in sh and run through with a for loop:

```
test_array=([a]=10 [b]=20 [c]=30)

for k in "${!test_array[@]}"
  do
  printf "%s\n" "$k=${test_array[$k]}"
done
```

And this only returns the last array element:

```
0=30
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3113285/297323

Comment: Thanks @FredrikPihl, Using the solution proposed by Paused until further notice, I have the same result, only the last array value is shown at key 0.

Comment: did you declare `test_array` as an associative array? `declare -A test_array`

Comment: You mean Posix `sh`? I don't know which program `shell` is.

Comment: @kvantour, just tried and is still the same. Note that I'm in sh, not bash.

Comment: @kvantour, right, sh, sorry, just edited my comment

Comment: In POSIX sh there are **no** associative arrays. You need to do some really dirty work to mimic these things. Here are some references: [BashFAQ/006](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_array_hacks_in_older_shells), [Associative arrays in Shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/688849/8344060), [U&L: Associative Arrays in Shell Scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111397/273492)

Comment: So, I was just checking the scipt on an Ubuntu 18.04 and it works. The sh I was initially testing on OSx, seems the Mac Shel is somehow different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this in bash.

Compare these two functions.  In the first, I am creating an array with integer indexes, in the second an associative array.  I got the expected results in bash.  I'm not sure which variant of shell you are using, so I don't know whether you need to add the declaration or quote the array keys or both.

```
x () 
{ 
    declare -a test_array;
    test_array=([a]=10 [b]=20 [c]=30);
    for k in "${!test_array[@]}";
    do
        printf "%s\n";
        echo "$k=${test_array[$k]}";
    done
}
y

y () 
{ 
    declare -A test_array;
    test_array=(["a"]=10 ["b"]=20 ["c"]=30);
    for k in "${!test_array[@]}";
    do
        printf "%s\n";
        echo "$k=${test_array[$k]}";
    done
}
x
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about Posix sh which does not have the `declare` statement and neither supports associative arrays

Comment: He does not specify posix sh in the question.  That was clarified after I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Associative arrays are feature of `bash 4`! It is not available in `sh`.

As **kvantour** pointed out in comments, we can mimic the behaviour of associative arrays in sh. See this [reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688849/associative-arrays-in-shell-scripts), [reference2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111397/associative-arrays-in-shell-scripts).