# On a mac, bash scripting shows uncertain behaviour w associative array (dictionaries)

Tags: bash, macos, unix, vector, zsh

First off (mac uses this `%` for what I am used to be `~$` ad input in the terminal, therefore I am going to use mac convention to indicate command launched:

```
~% echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
~% zsh --version
zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)
```

The test.sh (line numbers vim-style for convenient reading):

```
    1 #!/bin/bash
    2 # 
    3 declare -A myvector
    4 echo "wut?"
```

I am assuming zsh (which I don't know how to use) runs bash (I am born with it :_), but

```
~% chmod u+x ./test.sh
~% ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 3: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
wut?
```

Then executing:

```
~% . ./test.sh
wut?
```

I assume the . is zsh launching the script and without its bash.

I checked various questions on how to use **declare**, **typeset** in both *zsh* and *bash* from stackoverflow in unix.stackoverflow.com and askdifferent.stackoverflow.com

The problem is `man bash` and `man zshbuiltins` give all incogruent and nonworking way to use associative array.

Why I can't declare vector and use bash way (AND also as man zshbuiltins say I could).

The following doesn't work in no way possible
[How to iterate over associative arrays in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112687/how-to-iterate-over-associative-arrays-in-bash#3113285)

So changing it to

```
    ...
    3 declare -a myvector
    ...
```

so also initializing the vector with does not work

```
    myvector=(a 0 b 0 c 0)
```

nor

```
    myvector=("a" 0 "b" 0 "c" 0)
```

I am really at a loss here... should I just quit C.S. for another 5 years xD?

Comment: What's the output of `bash --version`?

Comment: @Grobu it is 
GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0)

Comment: Do you have several Bash interpreters installed? What's the output of `/bin/bash --version` then?

Comment: The error message `declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]` belongs to a pre-V4 Bash release (see file `./doc/bashref.html` in [this archive](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-doc-3.2.tar.gz)), so I suspect your `/bin/bash` might be MacOS' "stock" (outdated) version, while you have another Bash interpreter (possibly installed via `macports` or `brew`) that gets prioritized because of your PATH setup. If you type `which bash`, chances are it will point you to another location than `/bin/bash`. You can use that path in your scripts _shebang_ line.

Comment: On macOS, /bin/bash is only version 3.2.57, but associative arrays weren't added until version 4.0. You presumably have v5.2.26 installed somewhere else.

Comment: @Grobu I do use brew, 

```
/bin/bash --version

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22)
```

so 

```
bash --version

GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0
```

then

```
which bash

/usr/local/bin/bash
```

eidt : I edited 10 times... I am starting to get pissed at SO comments editor too :D

Comment: @GordonDavisson it is indeed like that. Thank you all

Comment: @splinux so you can just use `#! /usr/local/bin/bash` in your scripts and you'll feel at home

Comment: Since you are using a #! line instead of specifying the shell on invocation (i.e.   `bash ./test.sh`), the #! specifies the shell used to run your script, i.e. /bin/bash. I guess that without the #! line, zsh would run /bin/sh to execute your script. BTW, if you do inside your script a `echo $0`, you get some idea which shell is running it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am assuming zsh (which I don't know how to use) runs bash

No, `zsh` and `bash` are 2 completely different shells, each with their own syntax, builtin commands, etc.

> mac uses this % for what I am used to be ~$

Not exactly, that's just whatever string your `PS1` variable is set to in your `.profile` (or `.bash_profile` or `.zsh_profile`, whichever you use) or the system `.profile` by default. Type `PS1='fluffy bunny '` on the command line and hit enter to see it changed.

I don't know `zsh` but try this:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A assoc_arr=( ['foo']='bar', ['this']='that other thing' )
declare -p assoc_arr

echo ""

declare -a index_arr=( 'twas the' 'best of times' )
declare -p index_arr
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
declare -A assoc_arr=([foo]="bar," [this]="that other thing" )

declare -a index_arr=([0]="twas the" [1]="best of times")
```

That will run your script using the first version of `bash` found in your `PATH` regardless of whether it's called from `zsh` or `bash` or any other shell. If the above doesn't work for you then you have some version of `bash` that doesn't support `declare -A` first in your `PATH`.

`MacOS` comes with `zsh` as the default login shell and a very old version of `bash` to avoid some licensing issues, so either learn `zsh` or, if you're going to use `bash`, you should install a newer version (google "use bash on Mac" or similar).

Comment: Thanks @Ed. I should have been more precise: I meant zsh can run bash. Like an OS can run another OS or a compiler can cross compile etc etc. That was a waste of words on my side in hindsight. 

Its too removed from me the details of why using . insteaf og launching the script without the dot changes the execution path but your way of shebanging "env bash" works.

I'll figure out the rest.